# Prevent queue of data in writeCharacteristic of qlowenergyservice

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am sending slider values using the signal onValueChanged to a function where the slider value in int data type is converted to string and then to qbytearray and is written to the ble device as

> qDebug()<<"value from slider "<<value;
>
> service.writeCharacteristic(characteristic,value);
>
> qDebug()<<"value written"<<value;

where value is the slider value in qbytearray .

Now when writing , sometimes the slider value gets jumbled when written to the ble device .

Eg:

> value from slider 21
>
> value written 21

> value from slider 22
>
> value written 22

> value from slider 23
>
> value from slider 24

> value written 24
>
> value written 23

If I check the documentation, it says that if the writeCharacteristic is called multiple times , then it create a queue , where the data is saved and gets written .

Is it possible to prevent this queue formation ?
Or is there any other method like using thread ?

Comment: The code snippet you provided, do you run that from multiple threads concurrently?

Comment: I am not sure about threads . But the function is called multiple times within a small interval of time .